# UITableViewCell with strange behavior on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder

My view have 2 UITableViews.

The bottom button slides a table view to the front of the other as you can see at the images.

[image]

The problem is that when the table view slides up, the only clickable area turns out to the red area that I have painted on the second image.

If I touch outside this area, is actually touches the table view with green cells behind this one.

I tried disabling the userInteractionEnabled while the yellow table view is expanded but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should check userInteractionEnabled on your view hierarchy. If you have it disabled on one view, all subviews won't be interactive.
For example; if you're using UIImageView, its default value is 'NO'.

Comment: every view in the hierarchy is enabling user interaction